# Show sharedprefrence data to text field flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have sharedprefrence data called sectionhead so i am saving this at the time of login,what i trying to do is i need to fetch the data then show to a textfield,but it's retruning the print data but i can't access to the text field

```
 String sections = "";
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future tokendata = SharedPrefrence().getSectionHead();
    tokendata.then((data) {
      print(data);
      setState(() {
        var sections = data;
        return sections;
      });
    });

  }



label: Text(sections.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),),
```

Comment: Do you mean..you are getting nothing in the label part..?

Comment: yes@srikanth7785

Comment: In that case you did the assignment in the wrong way..I believe it should be `sections = data`..inside `setState`..hope it solves your issue..!Let me know if it worked for you..!

Comment: yes,sorry wrong code,i have updated the code,but still i can't show this in text @srikanth7785

Comment: Try removing `var`..in `setState`..before `sections`..

Comment: removing var made it work ..thanks man @srikanth7785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are using `var` before the `sections` variable..which makes it look like a new `variable`..and `data` will be assigned to the new variable..which is why it is not reflecting, even though you used `setState`..by removing `var`..there will be only one `sections` variable whose will be reflected at the `label` part..hope it makes some sense..

Feel free to ask for clarifications

Answer (score 0):

do it in your own initState as the default initState cannot be async.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
}

void init async() {
  Future tokendata = await SharedPrefrence().getSectionHead();
  sections = data;
}

~~~~~~~~

label: Text(sections.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),),
```